# Exercício em C, impressão de troco

Tags: c

Considere quatro moedas, de 25 centavos, 10, 5 e 1. Construa um programa em C que pergunte ao usuário quanto ele quer receber de troco e em seguida imprima a quantidade de moedas necessárias pra pagar o troco, entregando sempre o menor número possível de moedas. O programa deve ter um loop que obrigue o usuário colocar um valor positivo.

**fonte:**

```
#include <cc50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

int a = 25;
int b = 10;
int c = 5;
int d = 1;
float f = 0;

do
 printf("Quanto de troco deseja receber? ");
 f = GetFloat();
while ( f < 0 );

if ( f == 0 )
 printf("Obrigado volte sempre!\n");

if ( f > 0 )
 printf("Este troco exige %.2f moedas.\n", f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse problema é bem clássico de faculdade.

Basicamente o que tem que fazer é obter o valor do troco, e ir decrementando pelo valor das moedas disponíveis, da moeda de maior valor para a de menor valor enquanto faz a contagem das moedas.

segue uma resolução possível para o problema

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

    float a = 0.25;
    float b = 0.10;
    float c = 0.05;
    float d = 0.01;
    float f = 0;

    int moedas;
    do{
        printf("Quanto de troco deseja receber? ");
        scanf("%f",&f);
    }while(f < 0);

    while(f >= a) {
        f -= a;
        moedas++;
    }

    while(f >= b) {
        f -= b;
        moedas++;
    }

    while(f >= c) {
        f -= c;
        moedas++;
    }

    while(f >= d) {
        f -= d;
        moedas++;
    }

    printf("Este troco exige %d moedas.\nObrigado volte sempre!\n", moedas);

}
```

> Mais uma pergunta, em C não se pode modificar o valor de uma variável? Tentei usar o laço de repetição while mas não compilava, acusava um erro dizendo que não poderia mudar o valor da variável f,

No caso pela sintaxe, você está declarando novamente a mesma variável f, por isso o erro.

```
float f = GetFloat();
```

Também , como o @Matheus recomendo que use o scanf no lugar de `GetFloat()`, o trecho de código ficaria o seguinte

```
scanf("%f",&f);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica de sintaxe, não sabia. Sobre a função, sou obrigado a fazer com GetFloat(), é um exercício de curso.

Comment: Sem problemas, apenas não conseguia testar pois não tenho o arquivo cc50.h que deve conter essa função, então usei scanf que é o disponível no C.

Answer (score 0):

Nesta parte do código:

```
do
   printf("Quanto de troco deseja receber? ");
   float f = GetFloat();
while ( f < 0 );
```

Voce esqueceu as chaves, por isso está dando erro.
Faça:

```
do{
   printf("Quanto de troco deseja receber? ");
   float f = GetFloat();
}while ( f < 0 );
```

Comment: Fiz várias modificações no código, inclusive isso, e não funciona, é como se o valor global de f não mudasse com as chaves no do while.

Comment: Tire o float do f dentro do while e tente novamente.

Comment: Xara, porfavor utilize a a função scanf no lugar da GetFloat(),outra coisa como f já esta declarada la em cima voce não precisa declara-la novamente, no seu caso seria f = GetFloat(); e não float f = GetFloat();

Answer (score -3):

Basicamente o que tem que fazer é obter o valor do troco, e ir decrementando pelo valor das moedas disponíveis, da moeda de maior valor para a de menor valor enquanto faz a contagem das moedas.